# None of the programs in Arduino example is compiling

Tags: arduino-uno

I am new  to Arduino. I have connected the Arduino to the computer and I have installed the necessary drivers. But when I am compiling the Blink.ino program and other programs, which is present in the example, I am getting an compilation error. I have the IDE folder in D:\ drive

```
exec: "D:\\Arduino\\arduino-nightly\\tools-builder\\ctags\\5.8-arduino5/ctags": file does not exist
    Error compiling.
```

I don't know what to do. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things here look odd – but then I don't use Windows very often – I'd suggest that you download a fresh copy of the stock (not development) Arduino IDE. You can get it [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software).

What's odd looking too me is:

1. The double backslashes, they could be causing the file to appear not to exist, and
2. The `arduino-nightly` component in the path. That suggests to me that you're using a "bleeding edge" version of the IDE where problems are likely to creep in. These versions are for developers and people who like living on the edge (or who want to help with testing new features and the like).

One thing to do to check out the first oddity is to actually try to follow that path (both with and without the double backslashes). If the file is there (without the double backslashes) then it seems like something is odd with the path construction in the IDE.

Comment: The link which you gave is for downloading arduino 1.6.6 which is arduino- nightly

Comment: Hmm, did you try the Windows Installer (in the box on the right hand side) rather than the Hourly build? You might also try an older version. I'm on a Mac and my install (of 1.6.6) does not mention being "nightly."

Comment: Also, double check that the missing file, and the path to it, actually exist.

Comment: Yeah it worked perfectly well for older version i.e 1.6.5. Thanks @dlu